# Pre and Post in a Block[]

Tags: evaluation

Why does

```
Block[{$Pre = ( 1 + #) &}, 1]
```

produce `1` while

```
Block[{$PreRead = Print["hi"]}, 1]
```

produces

```
"hi"
1
```

?
In the `Block` block, shouldn't the expression have it's `Pre` evaluation as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `$Pre` and `$PreRead` cannot be set within a "line" of code and apply to that same "line" as well.  Your example with `$PreRead` is a false result because you did not make it a function.

Consider:

```
Block[{$PreRead = (Print["hi"]; #) &}, 1]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

If *outside* `Block` you set:

```
$PreRead = (Print["<<", #, ">>"]; #) &;
```

and then evaluate a `Block`:

```
Block[{x},
 1;
 2;
 3;
]
```

> ```
>  <<RowBox[{Block,[,RowBox[{RowBox[{{,x,}}],,,RowBox[{1,;,2,;,3,;}]}],]}]>>
> ```

You see that the entire "line" (I can't think of a better term at the moment) of code is sent to `$PreRead`, not individual parts of it.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  If I ever have to use `$Pre` or `$Post`, I have to evaluate them in a separate line, do my calculation on a second, and then remove their values on a third!  Also, when you say "false result," I don't quite understand.  What does the fact that it isn't a function have to do with it being evaluated?

Comment: @VF1 Because the `"hi"` you're seeing is just because the `Print` statement evaluated, and not as a result of `$PreRead` being correctly set. If it indeed were set correctly, as you had hoped, you should've seen two `"hi"` statements for the following `Block[{$PreRead = Print["hi"]}, 1; 1;]`

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @rm-rf Actually, if the rhs of the expression `$PreRead` is evaluated, I would assume that `$PreRead` has been set.  Anyways, regarding the fact that setting it doesn't change the first line - `$Pre = 1 + # &; 1` returns `2`.  Why is `CompoundExpression` special and `Block` not?

Comment: @VF1 I suspect you already had `$Pre` defined... try evaluating `$Pre =.` and then repeat your experiment. I get 1.